# com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.basicresourcepool$acquiretask acquisition attempt failed port number is not valid

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
WARN (BasicResourcePool.java:1841) - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@5ccb71f5 -- 
    Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, 
    we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30).
Last acquisition attempt exception:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number 49373/siya_hcm is not valid.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:580)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner$TaskThread.run(ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner.java:255)
28.06.2015 15:17:36 DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:422) - decremented pending_acquires: 1
28.06.2015 15:17:36 DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:1831) - An exception occurredwhile acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number 49373/siya_hcm is not valid.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:580)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner$TaskThread.run(ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner.java:255)
28.06.2015 15:17:36  WARN (BasicResourcePool.java:1841) - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@31dddcce -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Cl
earing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30).
Last acquisition attempt exception:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number 49373/siya_hcm is not valid.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:580)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner$TaskThread.run(ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner.java:255)
28.06.2015 15:17:36 DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:422) - decremented pending_acquires: 0
```

I am using spring hibernate integrated framework .

Following is my applicationContext.xml :-

```
<bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:49373/siya_hcm" />
    <property name="user" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="test@12345" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
</bean>
```

I am using sql server 2008.
I couldn't understand why this warning comes?
I have run other projects with the same configuration with other databases like mysql etc. But here, what is the problem?

Comment: Silly mistake from my side . Thanks definitely your comment help me. correct jdbcUrl is             jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:49373;databaseName=siya_hcm

Comment: You are welcome. So it seems that my comment did help you to resolve the issue; so I turned it into an answer; feel free to "accept" that one ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding your context; are you sure that "49373/siya_hcm" is a valid port number? I would guess that a valid port number should only consist of, well ... a number?